# Any chart library for funnel chart instead of highchart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highcharts

```
I need free chart library for funnel view. currently I am using highchart as I don't see any alternative library. If anyone knows about free library for funnel chart please let me know...
```

Is there any with D3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fusioncharts.com/   it is very  easy to create funnel in fusioncharts  see this sample  http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/5dDy4/

```
                    FusionCharts.ready(function () {
                var conversionChart = new FusionCharts({
                    type: 'funnel',
                    renderAt: 'chart-container',
                    width: '500',
                    height: '400',
                    dataFormat: 'json',
                    dataSource: {
                        "chart": {
                            "caption": "Conversion Funnel Analysis for last year",
                                "subcaption": "Harry's SuperMart Website",
                                "decimals": "1",
                                "labelDistance": "15",
                                "plotTooltext": "Success : $percentOfPrevValue",
                                //To show the values in percentage
                                "showPercentValues": "1",
                                "theme": "fint"
                        },
                            "data": [{
                            "label": "Unique Website Visits",
                                "value": "1460000"
                        }, {
                            "label": "Programme Details Section Visits",
                                "value": "930000"
                        }, {
                            "label": "Attempts to Register",
                                "value": "540000"
                        }, {
                            "label": "Successful Registrations",
                                "value": "210000"
                        }, {
                            "label": "Logged In",
                                "value": "190000"
                        }, {
                            "label": "Purchased on Introductory Offers",
                                "value": "120000"
                        }]
                    }
                });

                conversionChart.render();
            });
```

Comment: Is it free for commercial use?

Comment: well  it has a trial version

Answer (score 3):

This one uses D3

**Git Location:**: https://github.com/jakezatecky/d3-funnel

**Show me the demo**: http://jakezatecky.github.io/d3-funnel/